# How to wrap `AxeBuilder.analyse()` in a promise in Jasmine / Protractor?

Tags: asynchronous, jasmine, promise, protractor

I have been working on a Jasmine custom matcher to check if a page is accessible.

The important bit looks like this:

```
var _result = {};
AxeBuilder(browser.driver).analyze(function(results) {
    if (util.equals(results.violations.length, expected)) {
        _result.pass = true;
        _result.message = 'Selection was accessible.';
    } else {
        _result.pass = false;
        _result.message = results.violations;
    }
});
return result;
```

The problem I have is that `_result` (not `results`) is always an empty object.

I suspect the problem is that `AxeBuilder(...).analyze(...)` is async but does not return a promise.

My test is not being run from Karma it is initiated via my Protractor config.

If my suspicions are true, how would I go about wrapping it in a promise?

Answer (score 2):

If possible, You should use WebDriverJS promises provided within protractor

```
function builder() {
      return AxeBuilder(browser.driver).analyze(function(results) {
         var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
         if (util.equals(results.violations.length, expected)) {
           _result.pass = true;
           _result.message = 'Selection was accessible.';
           deferred.fulfill(_result);
         } else {
           _result.pass = false;
           _result.message = results.violations;
           deferred.reject(_result);
         }
         return deferred;
     });
}
```

Here is how you could use it,

```
 builder().then(function(_result) {
        console.log(_result.pass);
    }, function(err) {
       console.error(err);
 });
```

Comment: This is interesting and seems promising (no pun intended) but still isn't working for me.

Comment: I think `AxeBuilder(browser.driver).analyze` is failing. Is the callback within getting called? Maybe add a console log inside to see if it reaches there?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement callback concept to prevent execution of statement '*return result'* before result object is ready.  You can try with below code.

```
 var _result = {firstvalue:"test"};
 AxeBuilder(browser.driver).analyze(function(results,callback) {
      if (util.equals(results.violations.length, expected)) {
           _result.pass = true;
           _result.message = 'Selection was accessible.';
       } else {
         _result.pass = false;
         _result.message = results.violations;
      }
     callback(result);
  });

var callback=function(result){
   return result;
  }
```

Comment: I have been unsuccessful with this.

Comment: Sorry, the situation does not change `result.pass` is undefined.

Comment: @atwright147, create an object with any value, rather creating empty obejct var _result = {first:"Test"};

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with AxeBuilder. As u mentioned that AxeBuilder.analyze() is a async method, you need to return the `_result` variable inside the analyze method. Try the below code,

```
return AxeBuilder(browser.driver).analyze(function(results) {
  if (util.equals(results.violations.length, expected)) {
    _result.pass = true;
    _result.message = 'Selection was accessible.';
  } else {
    _result.pass = false;
    _result.message = results.violations;
  }
   return _result;
});
```

In your code you are returning the `_result`variable before the analyze method is executed.

Comment: Than you for the quick reply. That doesn't seem to work because it doesn't return a promise and the rest of my code executes before it has finished it's work. I think I need to wrap it in a promise (somehow).